# De Morgan’s law: Wikipedia proof, cannot follow part 1, step 3.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I would like to prove De Morgan’s laws and have tried to follow the Wikipedia proof. However, I am stuck in [part 1 of this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Part_1), line 3:

1: Let $x \in (A \cap B)^c $. Then, $ x \notin A \cap B $.

2: Because $ A \cap B  = \{y | y  \in A \wedge y \in B \}$, it must be the case that $ x \notin A$ or $x \notin B$.

3: If $x \notin A$, then $x \in A^c$, so $x \in A^c \cup B^c$

Why is the part after the comma (“so, ...”) correct and where is it coming from?

Thank you.

Comment: If $x$ is in set $A$, then $x$ will be also in set $A$ plus something (set-union).

Comment: Recall that $x \in A \cup B \text {  iff  } x \in A \text {  or  } x \in B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ belongs to a set, then it belongs to every larger set. So, if $x\in A^\complement$, then it also belongs to $A^\complement\cup B^\complement$.